# Scrapy/Python: run logic after yielded requests are finished

Tags: python, scrapy

What I do:

```
def parse(self, response):

    products_urls = response.css('.product-item a::attr(href)').extract()

    for product_url in product_urls:
        yield Request(product_url, callback=self.parse_product)

    print( "Continue doing stuff...." )


def parse_product(self, response):
    title = response.css('h1::text').extract_first()
    print( title )
}
```

In this example, the code will first output `Continue doing stuff..` and after that it will print product titles. I would like it to run otherwise, first do requests and print titles, and only then print `Continue doing stuff..`

UPDATE:
@Georgiy in comments asked if I require previously scraped product data.

Answer is yes, this is simplified example. After data is fetched I want to manipulate that data.

Comment: It depends on.. what exactly ""Continue doing stuff...." your application is expected to do?. Does it require previously scraped product data?

Comment: @Georgiy I updated my question with answer to your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the logic to the `parse_product` function. For example:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        products_urls = response.css('.product-item a::attr(href)').extract()

        self.count = len(products_urls)
        if self.count == 0:
            self.onEnd()
        else:
            for product_url in product_urls:
                yield Request(product_url, callback=self.parse_product)

    def onEnd(self):
        print( "Continue doing stuff...." )


    def parse_product(self, response):
        title = response.css('h1::text').extract_first()
        print( title )
        self.count -= 1
        if (self.count == 0):
            self.onEnd()
```